# UTF-8 error with Python and gettext

Tags: python, localization, gettext

I use UTF-8 in my editor, so all strings displayed here are UTF-8 in file.

I have a python script like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
...
parser = optparse.OptionParser(
  description=_('automates the dice rolling in the classic game "risk"'), 
  usage=_("usage: %prog attacking defending"))
```

Then I used xgettext to get everything out and got a .pot file which can be boiled down to:

```
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=CHARSET\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

#: auto_dice.py:16
msgid "automates the dice rolling in the classic game \"risk\""
msgstr ""
```

After that, I used msginit to get a `de.po` which I filled in like this:

```
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

#: auto_dice.py:16
msgid "automates the dice rolling in the classic game \"risk\""
msgstr "automatisiert das Würfeln bei \"Risiko\""
```

Running the script, I get the following error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/optparse.py", line 1664, in print_help
    file.write(self.format_help().encode(encoding, "replace"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 60: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: What is the type of `_("usage: %prog attacking defending")`?  i.e. what does `print type(_("usage: %prog attacking defending"))` print?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That error means you've called encode on a bytestring, so it tries to decode it to Unicode using the system default encoding (ascii on Python 2), then re-encode it with whatever you've specified.

Generally, the way to resolve it is to call `s.decode('utf-8')` (or whatever encoding the strings are in) before trying to use the strings. It might also work if you just use unicode literals: `u'automates...'` (that depends on how strings are substituted from .po files, which I don't know about).

This sort of confusing behaviour is improved in Python 3, which won't try to convert bytes to unicode unless you specifically tell it to.

Comment: the `u"literal"` does not work, but `decode("utf-8")` works. Not very nice, but works.

Answer (score 5):

My suspicion is that the problem is caused by `_("string")` returning a byte string and not a Unicode string.

The obvious workaround is this:

```
parser = optparse.OptionParser(
        description=_('automates the dice rolling in the classic game "risk"').decode('utf-8'),
        usage=_("usage: %prog attacking defending").decode('utf-8'))
```

But that feels wrong.

[ugettext](http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html#gettext.NullTranslations.ugettext) or [install(True)](http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html#gettext.NullTranslations.install) may help.

The [Python gettext docs](http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html#localizing-your-module) give these examples:

```
import gettext
t = gettext.translation('spam', '/usr/share/locale')
_ = t.ugettext
```

or:

```
import gettext
gettext.install('myapplication', '/usr/share/locale', unicode=1)
```

---

I am trying to reproduce your problem, and even if I use `install(unicode=1)`, I get back a byte string (`str` type).

Either I am using gettext incorrectly, or I am missing a character coding declaration in my .po/.mo file.

I will update when I know more.

```
xlt = _('automates the dice rolling in the classic game "risk"')
print type(xlt)
if isinstance(xlt, str):
    print 'gettext returned a str (wrong)'
    print xlt
    print xlt.decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8')
elif isinstance(xlt, unicode):
    print 'gettext returned a unicode (right)'
    print xlt.encode('utf-8')
```

(One other possibility is to use escapes or Unicode code points in the .po file, but that doesn't sound like fun.)

(Or you could look at your system's `.po` files to see how they handle non-ASCII characters.)

Comment: Using `dk = gettext.translation(....., languages=['dk'])` and then `dk.install(unicode=True)` solved the problem for me. This solution allows for more languages.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with this, but it appears to be a known bug in 2.6 that's been fixed in 2.7:

http://bugs.python.org/issue2931

If it's not feasible for you to use 2.7, try this workaround:

http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2006-May/065458.html