# MySQL Data Export: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 60: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, google-cloud-sql

When I try to dump data from my Cloud SQL database through MySQL Workspace, I get this in the log of the export process:

```
Error executing task: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 60: ordinal not in range(128)

Error executing task local variable 'p1' referenced before assignment
```

What's causing this and how do I solve it?

EDIT: It works when dumping data from a local MySQL server, so the problem occurs only when trying to dump from Google Cloud SQL. I still don't know why it happens.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 error with Python and gettext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545197/utf-8-error-with-python-and-gettext)

Comment: I don't see the duplication, I don't use Python, I'm only using the MySQL Workspace GUI to export data from a database.

Comment: ASCII characters codes go from 0x00 to 0x7F. What you have there is a character code 0xC3, which cannot be an ASCII-encoded character. Somewhere you should be able to tell it which encoding to use, e.g. in UTF-8 it would represent Ã.

Comment: But where does this character code come from? I have checked all records in the database and there is no non-ascii characters stored.

Comment: The reason for the error is as @AndrewMorton stated.  It is not clear however, from the data you've provided when this happens apart from when using Google Cloud SQL.  Are you still experiencing this issue?  If not, can you post the solution or your findings?  If so, can you post more details such as the command you're running to dump data from Cloud SQL, where you're running it, what type of data does this DB contain, what encoding do you use for your string data?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message. The problem was, that in my local path (where I wanted to save the backup) a folder had a french character é. When saved it in another folder, then it worked